# How can I convert this Local time to UTC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

honestly I'm a liitle bit confused and don't know how to solve this issue so if the question is kind of silly I'm sorry :)
so the situation is I have a time range that I get from server which is for reservation time range for a product consider this two:

```js
"startWorkingHour": "0001-01-01T08:00:00",
"finishWorkingHour": "0001-01-01T17:00:00"
```

these time are UTC times. and the problem is I need to somehow convert user selected time which is local to UTC and that time must be in between of those two times. for example user selected 8:00 AM from time picker and format is like `2021-07-05T03:30:12.498Z` and I don't want this I want this to be `2021-07-05T08:00:12.498Z` so my server could accept it. how can I achieve that?

Comment: So you're trying to convert local dates to UTC for comparison in your server?

Comment: Yes, actually its a reservation function that my time should be between those two times.

Comment: But if I use local for example 3:30AM, server send me error but I actually choose 8:00 AM.

Comment: Exactly. I was answering as you wrote this. You want to convert to UTC from local via `.toUTCString()`

Comment: @JoelHager sorry, i didn't notice your answer :d

Comment: I was actually posting it *while* you commented here, then I saw it and I didn't want you to think I just stole your answer. haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You convert to UTC via `toUTCString()`

```js
const dates = {
startWorkingHour: "0001-01-01T08:00:00",
finishWorkingHour: "0001-01-01T17:00:00"
}

const date = new Date()

console.log(date, date.toUTCString(), new Date(dates.startWorkingHour).toString())
```

Comment: Exactly what I want! Thank you so much.